# YouTube API - Dynamically change parameters/playerVars

Tags: javascript, html, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

In my current project, I've got a YT Player as part of it, that has options to have the parameters changed to various options.

So, if the user wanted to toggle autoplay they could etc.

But I'm not sure how to call the parameters again.

---

The code is:

```
var player;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()
    {
    player = new YT.Player('youtube',
        {
        height: '390',
        width: '640',
        videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
        playerVars:
            {
            autoplay: 0, // start automatically
            controls: 0, // don't show the controls (we can't click them anyways)
            modestbranding: 1, // show smaller logo
            loop: 1 // loop when complete
            },
        events:
            {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });
    }
```

---

I've tried calling player.playerVars.autoplay and player.autoplay, but the first doesn't get recognized and the second doesn't work.

Any help is appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could add a variable to change autoplay status.

```
/* body html */
     <select id="autoPlayOptions">
      <option value="1">autoplay</option>
      <option value="0">manually</option> 
    </select>
/* body html */
    <script>
/* more code */
    var player;
      var autoPlayAction = $("#autoPlayOptions").val();
      player = new YT.Player('player', {
        videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
        playerVars: { 'autoplay': autoPlayAction, 'controls': 0 },
        events: {
          'onReady': onPlayerReady, 
          'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange,
        }
      });

/* more code */
    </script>
```

hope it help!